# RegEx swap positions of elements in filename

Tags: regex

I am using LameXP to convert and encode audio files. These files are grouped poorly, but contain info in their filenames that could be used for this. Examples of files are as follows.

```
Genji-00000005818F.0B2-He'll talk.ogg
Tracer-00000005818C.0B2-Do you think Maximilien will talk_.ogg
Tracer-00000005818E.0B2-What does that mean_.ogg
Winston-00000005818D.0B2-He just deals with the money.ogg
```

LameXP offers a renaming tool that utilizes RegEx for find and replace. I would like to **move the file ID** (0000000XXXXX) **to the beginning before the character name.** What expression would I use to isolate the data ID and move it to the front?

Ideally, files would end up like this:

```
00000005818F_Genji-He'll talk.ogg
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more infomation that how the file name is formatted.

According to the examples you provided, this should do the trick:

#### Regex

```
^(.+?)-([0-9A-F]+)\.[0-9A-F]+-
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `(.+?)` Any characters, as few as possible, use this to capture author name, and put it in group 1
- `-` A dash
- `([0-9A-F]+)` Any hexidecimal characters, put it in group 2
- `\.` A dot
- `[0-9A-F]+` Another cascade of hexidecimal characters, use this to capture `0B2`
- `-` A dash

#### Substitution

```
\2_\1-
```

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/fZ20lh/1/)